# C++ Read array from file in specified range

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a file which contains array like this :

```
5
23
232
44
53
43
```

so line contains number of elements. Which means number of elements need to read. And create a array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
fstream mystream("file.txt");
int ArraySize;
int* array;

ArraySize = ......... //read first line

for(int i = 2; i < ArraySize; i++){
...............//add elements to the array
}
```

Comment: There is no single question mark in your **question**. What do you want from us? Guess? Specify what's the problem. This is not a code providing site

Comment: u really want SO to provide code for `//read first line`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat a `std::ifstream` as you would `std::cin`...

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream fs("/tmp/file.txt");

    int arr_size;
    fs >> arr_size; // gets first number in file.

    int* arr = new int[arr_size]; // could also use std::vector

    // collect next arr_size values in file.
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
        fs >> arr[i];
    //  std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }

    delete [] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why answer a question with no question whatsoever? OP did not state the problem. He implied that we'll write the code for him, which should not be the case

Comment: Downvoter, what's wrong?

Comment: @Fureeish because his problem is so obvious and so common.

Comment: "so common" which means it should be easy to find a solution by simply googling.

Comment: @Fureeish perhaps you are correct, but people will later Google and find this answer... maybe :)

Comment: duplicating existing solutions is not a good thing imo

Comment: @Fureeish then you should flag as duplicate...

Comment: i agree - the OP hasn't tried anything, we should not do peoples class assignments if they dont even try a bit. But the answer is correct

Comment: @Charles just a minor remark, but I think you don't need to include <iostream>

Comment: @Charles, done.